# How does ajax async: false option work under the hood?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I make an ajax call and pass `async: false`, it makes an asynchronous request but it stop the code execution until the request is done (making it synchronous).

How does it work under the hood? How can it make a async request become synchronous?

I'm trying to implement the same logic and want to understand better how it works.

Comment: It's a flag on an `XMLHttpRequest`. I don't know why you'd want to implement synchronous logic though, as it's being eradicated as it's terrible practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery uses the XMLHttpRequest object. It has a synchronous mode built-in (which is handled in native code).

As you noticed, it blocks all other code execution. As a result of this that feature is **deprecated** and should not be used.

Note that this isn't converting asynchronous code to synchronous code, there is no technique which can do that in the general case (although `await` can give the illusion of synchronous code within promise).